# GPUImage and GPUImageView : App terminated due to memory error

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, gpuimage

I am using a GPUImage and many GPUImageView instances. The purpose is to display the original image, layer several slices of filtered images on top, and finally animate the slice filters slowly across the original image. Imagine an image with some Sepia bars rolling across to show the normal image and sepia image in sections.

I wrapped this functionality in a subclass of UIView as seen below:

```
import Foundation
import QuartzCore

class FilteredImageMaskView : UIView {

init(frame: CGRect, image: UIImage){
    super.init(frame: frame);

    let imageViewFrame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, 0.0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

    let origImage = GPUImagePicture(image: image);
    origImage.forceProcessingAtSizeRespectingAspectRatio(imageViewFrame.size);

    // Display the original image without a filter
    let imageView = GPUImageView(frame: imageViewFrame);
    origImage.addTarget(imageView);
    origImage.processImageWithCompletionHandler(){
        origImage.removeAllTargets();

        var contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.contentMode = contentMode;

        // Width of the unfiltered region
        let regularWidth: CGFloat = 30.0;
        // Width of filtered region
        let filterWidth: CGFloat = 30.0;

        // How much we are moving each bar
        let totalXMovement = (regularWidth + filterWidth) * 2;

        // The start X position
        var currentXForFilter: CGFloat = -totalXMovement;

        // The filter being applied to an image
        let filter = GPUImageSepiaFilter();
        filter.intensity = 0.5;
        // Add the filter to the originalImage
        origImage.addTarget(filter);

        let filteredViewCollection = FilteredViewCollection(filteredViews: [GPUImageView]());

        // Iterate over the X positions until the whole image is covered
        while(currentXForFilter < imageView.frame.width + totalXMovement){
            let frame = CGRectMake(currentXForFilter, imageViewFrame.origin.y, imageViewFrame.width, imageViewFrame.height);
            var filteredView = GPUImageView(frame: frame);
            filteredView.clipsToBounds = true;
            filteredView.layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityTopLeft;

            // This is the slice of the overall image that we are going to display as filtered
            filteredView.layer.contentsRect = CGRectMake(currentXForFilter / imageViewFrame.width, 0.0, filterWidth / imageViewFrame.width, 1.0);
            filteredView.fillMode = kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatio;

            filter.addTarget(filteredView);

            // Add the filteredView to the super view
            self.addSubview(filteredView);

            // Add the filteredView to the collection so we can animate it later
            filteredViewCollection.filteredViews.append(filteredView);

            // Increment the X position           
            currentXForFilter += regularWidth + filterWidth;
        }

        origImage.processImageWithCompletionHandler(){
            filter.removeAllTargets();

            // Move to the UI thread
            ThreadUtility.runOnMainThread(){
                // Add the unfiltered image
                self.addSubview(imageView);
                // And move it behind the filtered slices
                self.sendSubviewToBack(imageView);

                // Animate the slices slowly across the image
                UIView.animateWithDuration(20.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, animations: { [weak filteredViewCollection] in
                    if let strongfilteredViewCollection = filteredViewCollection {
                        if(strongfilteredViewCollection.filteredViews != nil){
                            for(var i = 0; i < strongfilteredViewCollection.filteredViews.count; i++){
                                strongfilteredViewCollection.filteredViews[i].frame.origin.x += totalXMovement;
                                strongfilteredViewCollection.filteredViews[i].layer.contentsRect.origin.x += (totalXMovement / imageView.frame.width);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, completion: nil);
            }
        }
    }
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder);
}

}

class FilteredViewCollection {
    var filteredViews: [GPUImageView]! = [GPUImageView]();

    init(filteredViews: [GPUImageView]!){
        self.filteredViews = filteredViews;
    }
}
```

An instance of `FilteredImageMaskView` is added programmatically to a view in a viewController. When that viewController is dismissed, the assumption is that the resources will be disposed - I was careful to avoid retain cycles. When I watch the memory consumption in the debugger on a real device, the memory does drop appropriately when the viewController is dismissed. However, if I repeatedly load that viewController to look at the image, then dismiss it, then reload it again, I will eventually encounter "App terminated due to memory error"

If I wait a while after dismissing the viewController, the memory errors seem less frequent which leads me to believe the memory is still being released after the viewController is dismissed...? But I have also seen the error after only a couple times of not so rapid opening and closing of the viewController.

I must be using the GPUImage and/or GPUImageView inefficiently and I am looking for guidance.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** See below for the view controller implementation.

```
import UIKit

class ViewImageViewController: UIViewController, FetchImageDelegate {

    var imageManager = ImageManager();

    @IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageManager.fetchImageAsync(delegate: self);
    }

    // This callback is dispatched on the UI thread
    func imageFetchCompleted(imageData: [UInt8]) {
        let imageView = FilteredImageMaskView(frame: self.mainView.frame, image: UIImage(data: imageData));
        mainView.addSubview(imageView);

        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(10.0), target: self, selector: Selector("displayReminder"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false);
    }

    func displayReminder(){
        // Show an alert or message here
    }

}

class ImageManager {

    func fetchImageAsync(delegate: FetchImageDelegate) {
        // This dispatches a high priority background thread
        ThreadUtility.runOnHighPriorityBackgroundThread() { [weak delegate] in
            // Get the image (This part could take a while in the real implementation)
            var imageData = [UInt8]();

            // Move to the UI thread
            ThreadUtility.runOnMainThread({
                if let strongDelegate = delegate {
                    strongDelegate.imageFetchCompleted(imageData);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now that I am looking through this stripped down version, does passing `self` to the `ImageManager` create a retain cycle even though I reference it `weak`ly to the background thread? Can I pass that as a weak reference right from the `ViewImageViewController`? It is certainly possible that the `ViewImageViewController` is dismissed before the `fetchImageAsync` method completes and the callback is called.

**EDIT:** I think I found the issue. If you look at the `ViewImageViewController` in the callback, I create an NSTimer and pass self. My suspicion is that is creating a retain cycle if the viewController is dismissed before the timer executes. That would explain why if I wait a few extra seconds, I don't get the memory error - because the timer fires and the viewController disposes properly. Here is the fix (I think).

```
// This is on the ViewImageViewController
var timer: NSTimer!;

// Then instead of creating a new variable, assign the timer to the class variable
self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(10.0), target: self, selector: Selector("displayReminder"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false);

// And finally, on dismiss of the viewcontroller (viewWillDisappear or back button click event, or both)
func cancelTimer() {
    if(self.timer != nil){
        self.timer.invalidate();
        self.timer = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give more info about the view controller? Is it in fact being deallocated? If you have a memory leak, the problem would not be the code you've shown at all.

Comment: Certainly. I will update the OP.

Comment: @matt added per your request... and you might be right... see above

Comment: Pretty sure I got it by looking more closely at the VC. Thanks for the tip and direction. Testing thoroughly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the issue. If you look at the `ViewImageViewController` in the callback, I create an NSTimer and pass self. My suspicion is that is creating a retain cycle if the viewController is dismissed before the timer executes. That would explain why if I wait a few extra seconds, I don't get the memory error - because the timer fires and the viewController disposes properly. Here is the fix (I think).

```
// This is on the ViewImageViewController
var timer: NSTimer!;

// Then instead of creating a new variable, assign the timer to the class variable
self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(10.0), target: self, selector: Selector("displayReminder"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false);

// And finally, on dismiss of the viewcontroller (viewWillDisappear or back button click event, or both)
func cancelTimer() {
    if(self.timer != nil){
        self.timer.invalidate();
        self.timer = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very possible. See my discussion of timers and retain cycles - starts about 2/3 of the way thru this section: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_unusual_memory_management_situations As I quote the docs, "The target object is retained by the timer and released when the timer is invalidated." My example is a repeating timer; the example of a single-shot long-interval timer that never gets a chance to fire didn't occur to me! I'll make a note to myself to include that in any future editions of the book.

Comment: @matt indeed it appears this was the issue. Now everything disposes properly since implementing the code above. Sometimes it take a fine toothed comb and some patience to find these pesky retains :-D

Comment: Well, it takes looking in the right place. You were looking in the wrong place; your GPUImage stuff was a total red herring, and I was the one whose told you so and got you looking in the right place. But I told you that for free, so in the end you threw away 100 points of your own rep, to no purpose!

Comment: Yeah.. kind of wish I hadn't started the bounty. Or, that you could award to the person that pointed the right direction.

Comment: Well, obviously I could have written my advice to you - it's the view _controller_ that's leaking - as an answer instead of a comment, in an attempt to earn the bounty. But I'm not going to bother doing that. :) And after all, you _did_ actually _find_ the answer. So you got 10 points back from me when I upvoted you for doing that. :)))) But the lesson is: thinking is better than setting a bounty.

Answer (score 0):

The FilteredImageMaskView is strongly referenced in the block of processImageWithCompletionHandler, which is likely to form a retain cycle. Try to use a weak self instead in the block